# Pair completion in Vim

Tags: vim

I do my coding in Vim and recently have been getting more annoyed by its pair completion features. I don't really see the need for pair completion in general as I tend to naturally try to close pairs myself (by pair here I mean type the closing ')' of a set of parentheses, for example). What really annoys me is when I have text already written and to surround it by quotes for example I'll be at the beginning of the word, type ' and then two will pop up right over there rather than just 1 and then me pivoting to the end of the word and typing the other exclamation point. Anyways, that's it for my rant, so any help on stopping my vim from doing this would be appreciated. I use spfvim-13 (https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) and have only modified the .vimrc slightly. I wasn't able to pinpoint exactly from where this specific issue arises.

Comment: Vim "distributions" like _spf-13_ and _Janus_ lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a native vim behavior, it's definitely some plugin causing it. I can't pin-point a particular plugin that spf13 might be having for this, I looked for popular ones I know, like simple_pairs, delimitMate etc.

Best way to investigate what's causing is to just see the output of `:verbose imap '` and you'll come to know where it's being set and then remove that plugin / setting.

Comment: I was able to narrow it down to vim-autoclose and then disable it. I appreciate the tip! @Dhruva